# С каким словом согласовывать причастие?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

Это были отношения коллег-единомышленников, каждый на своем месте выполнявших
одну миссию...
Или ВЫПОЛНЯВШИЙ (ед. ч.)?
И наверное лучше КАЖДЫЙ ИЗ КОТОРЫХ?

Comment: Eсли Вам известнен источник, желательно на него ссылаться. "Отношения ученика и учителя продолжались — только теперь вышли на качественно иной уровень: это были отношения коллег-единомышленников, каждый на своем месте  выполнявших одну миссию — служение татарскому народу." (http://www.idmedina.ru/books/materials/faizhanov/3/plenary_uzeev.ht)

Comment: Иногда специально упрощаю предложение для облегчения восприятия...

Comment: Как правило, ответ тоже получается упрощенным. Например, если не знать, что в скрытой от глаз части предложения стоит тире, можно посоветовать  выделить присоединительную конструкцию с помощью тире.

Comment: Спасибо, буду это учитывать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отношения ученика и учителя продолжались — только теперь вышли на качественно иной уровень: **это были отношения** (кого?) **коллег-единомышленников,** (каких?) **выполнявших, каждый на своем месте,  одну миссию** — служение татарскому народу.

1) **Исходная структура**: Они (мн.ч. И.п.), **каждый** (из них, ед. ч. И.п.) **на своем месте,** выполняли одну миссию. Мы имеем обособленное приложение, согласованное с местоимением ***они*** И.п.

2) В заданном предложении с причастием обособленный оборот **сохраняется в начальной форме (ед.ч. И.п,** нет согласования в Р.п. мн.ч.). Таким образом, при отсутствии согласования (в Р.п.) обособленный оборот приобретает черты **присоединительного оборота**,  хотя по-прежнему может **обособляться запятыми.**

**Тире здесь слишком сильный знак,** а при наличии других тире еще и нежелательный.

3) По смыслу оборот относится и к субъекту действия, и к действию, обозначенному причастием, но грамматически у**же имеет бОльшую степень свободы**, в том числе и по позиции в предложении. Конечно, его удобнее расположить после причастия, но это уже не обязательно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, считаете ли Вы исходный вариант допустимым.

Comment: Думаю, что нет. Там не прослеживаются обязательные грамматические связи. Оборот "каждый на своем месте"   не связан с другими словами, поэтому его надо обособлять. Сравнить: Это были отношения коллег-единомышленников, когда каждый на своем месте выполняет одну миссию. Здесь видно, что "каждый" - это субъект действия, обозначенного глаголом "выполнять". Поэтому в обороте "каждый на своем месте выполнявших " ему нет места.

Answer (score 2):

> Это были отношения коллег-единомышленников, каждый на своем месте
>   выполнявших одну миссию.

Предложение можно исправить перестановкой слов:

***Это были отношения коллег-единомышленников, выполнявших – каждый на своем месте – одну миссию.***

Answer (score 1):

Здесь два разных высказывания: 1) все выполняли (мн. число) одну миссию, 2) каждый делал (ед. число) это на своём месте. Компактно объединить их, оставив один глагол, можно так:

> Это были отношения коллег-единомышленников, выполнявших одну миссию,
>   каждый - на своем месте.

Здесь второе (уточняющее) высказывание упрощено тем, что подразумеваемое "делал это" заменено на тире.

Answer (score 1):

> Отношения ученика и учителя продолжались — только теперь вышли на качественно иной уровень: это были отношения коллег-единомышленников, каждый на своем месте выполнявших одну миссию — служение татарскому народу. ([Содружество Фаизханова и Марджани](http://www.idmedina.ru/books/materials/faizhanov/3/plenary_uzeev.htm))

По-моему, так писать неверно. "Каждый на своем месте" — присоединительная конструкция, относящаяся к  слову *выполнявших*. Она должна стоять после этого слова и выделаться запятыми или тире.

**Это были отношения коллег-единомышленников, выполнявших, каждый на своем месте, одну миссию — служение татарскому народу.**

Comment: Вопросики: 1) Вы отличаете присоединительную конструкцию от обособленного оборота? Вроде бы у присоединительного оборота более свободная позиция, чем у просто обособленного.  2) Присоединительный оборот при отсутствии союзов вроде бы должен обособляться тире, а не запятыми.

Comment: На мой, непрофессиональный, взгляд, присоединительные члены предложения (https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html) — один из случаев обособленного оборота. "Часто при этом используется тире вместо запятой" (там же). Но можно и запятую поставить: Довольно поздно явился ещё гость, во фраке... (Герцен); Ночью я стою у орудия, дневальным (Катаев).

Comment: Под присоединительные конструкции (ПК) списывают всё, что имеет дополнительное значение. Но это семантика, а  как грамматически отличить ПК , чем они, к примеру, отличаются от обособленных членов или вставных конструкций. Требуется четкое определение, отличительный признак.  Например:  Довольно поздно явился ещё гость, во фраке... Обычное обособленное несогласованное определение. Что в нём присоединительного?

Comment: А вы читали мой вопрос о пояснительных определениях? Там было обсуждение на тему отличия обособленных и пояснительно-уточняющих определений. Присоединительными, на мой взгляд, могут быть и те и другие. Например, пояснительное определение, обособленное тире, передающее дополнительную информацию.